# Google Sheets API for Python: Empty charts when duplicating a worksheet

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, worksheet

Suppose I have two spreadsheets of almost the same structure:

**Spreadsheet A**:
*[Sheet1(Charts and data summary)][Sheet2 (Data)][Sheet3(Data)]*...

**Spreadsheet B**:
*[Sheet1(**Empty**)][Sheet2 (Data)][Sheet3(Data)]*...

A.Sheet1 contains manually created charts and aggregated data from A.Sheet2 and A.Sheet3.

Spreadsheet B has the same worksheet ordering and worksheet names as in Spreadsheet A. The task is to copy Sheet1 from A to B so that all charts and formulas should be mapped to the data from corresponding worksheets of B of the same name.

So I'm using the following code to copy entire Sheet1 from A to B:

```
def duplicate_worksheet(from_spreadsheet_id,
                        sheet_id,
                        to_spreadsheet_id,
                        credentials,
                        title=None):

    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

    copy_sheet_to_another_spreadsheet_request_body = {
        'destination_spreadsheet_id': to_spreadsheet_id
    }
    request = service.spreadsheets().sheets().copyTo(spreadsheetId=from_spreadsheet_id,
                                                     sheetId=sheet_id,
                                                     body=copy_sheet_to_another_spreadsheet_request_body)

    response = request.execute()
    if title:
        new_sheet_id = response['sheetId']
        new_title = title
        rename_worksheet(to_spreadsheet_id, new_sheet_id, new_title, credentials)
```

After copying, **B.Sheet1** looks like this:
[image]

Here we can see that aggregated tables copied successfully but 2 charts are empty (Instead, `No data` message is shown]). The spreadsheet Itself is missing all specified chart data ranges and links, which are supposed to persist after copying from A. So my question is how to "deepcopy" a worksheet and keep all chart data and links? (Of course in case If It's possible by using Google API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart is being copied empty, due to the  [Method: spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo) endpoint only copies ***one sheet*** to the other spreadsheet, therefore if one chart is built using data from another sheet, it will lose it.

As a workaround, you could edit [the empty chart's properties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#edit_a_charts_properties) with the properties of your original chart, so it looks as it were a direct copy of it as you are desiring.

You will need to use the [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) endpoint. In Python your request will look like this:

```
body = {
    'requests': requests
}
response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    body=body).execute()
```